# Azure IoT Edge error after removing x509 cert and key-pair

Tags: azure, azure-iot-edge

My goal is to reset a device that is already connected to IoT Central by removing the x509 certificate file and deleting the key-pair from the HSM.

````
Sep 22 17:04:11 bobcat systemd[1]: aziot-identityd.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 18119.
Sep 22 17:04:11 bobcat systemd[1]: Stopped Azure IoT Identity Service.
Sep 22 17:04:11 bobcat aziot-edged[404821]: 2022-09-22T17:04:11Z [WARN] - The daemon could not start up successfully: Could not retrieve device information
Sep 22 17:04:11 bobcat aziot-edged[404821]: 2022-09-22T17:04:11Z [WARN] -         caused by: HTTP request error
Sep 22 17:04:11 bobcat aziot-edged[404821]: 2022-09-22T17:04:11Z [WARN] -         caused by: connection error: Connection reset by peer (os error 104)
Sep 22 17:04:11 bobcat aziot-edged[404821]: 2022-09-22T17:04:11Z [WARN] - Requesting device reprovision.
Sep 22 17:04:11 bobcat aziot-edged[404821]: 2022-09-22T17:04:11Z [WARN] - The reprovisioning operation failed
Sep 22 17:04:11 bobcat systemd[1]: Started Azure IoT Identity Service.
Sep 22 17:04:11 bobcat aziot-identityd[404892]: 2022-09-22T17:04:11Z [ERR!] - Failed to provision with IoT Hub, and no valid device backup was found: internal error
Sep 22 17:04:11 bobcat aziot-identityd[404892]: 2022-09-22T17:04:11Z [ERR!] - service encountered an error
Sep 22 17:04:11 bobcat aziot-identityd[404892]: 2022-09-22T17:04:11Z [ERR!] - caused by: internal error
Sep 22 17:04:11 bobcat aziot-identityd[404892]: 2022-09-22T17:04:11Z [ERR!] - caused by: could not create certificate
Sep 22 17:04:11 bobcat aziot-identityd[404892]: 2022-09-22T17:04:11Z [ERR!] - caused by: internal error
Sep 22 17:04:11 bobcat aziot-identityd[404892]: 2022-09-22T17:04:11Z [ERR!] - caused by: could not create certificate
Sep 22 17:04:11 bobcat aziot-identityd[404892]: 2022-09-22T17:04:11Z [ERR!] - caused by: old device identity certificate, which should contain the common name field required for registration, could not be retrieved
Sep 22 17:04:11 bobcat aziot-identityd[404892]: 2022-09-22T17:04:11Z [ERR!] -    0: <unknown>
Sep 22 17:04:11 bobcat aziot-identityd[404892]:    1: <unknown>
Sep 22 17:04:11 bobcat aziot-identityd[404892]:    2: <unknown>
Sep 22 17:04:11 bobcat aziot-identityd[404892]:    3: <unknown>
Sep 22 17:04:11 bobcat aziot-identityd[404892]:    4: <unknown>
Sep 22 17:04:11 bobcat aziot-identityd[404892]:    5: <unknown>
Sep 22 17:04:11 bobcat aziot-identityd[404892]:    6: <unknown>
Sep 22 17:04:11 bobcat aziot-identityd[404892]:    7: <unknown>
Sep 22 17:04:11 bobcat aziot-identityd[404892]:    8: <unknown>
Sep 22 17:04:11 bobcat aziot-identityd[404892]:    9: <unknown>
Sep 22 17:04:11 bobcat aziot-identityd[404892]:   10: <unknown>
Sep 22 17:04:11 bobcat aziot-identityd[404892]:   11: __libc_start_main
Sep 22 17:04:11 bobcat aziot-identityd[404892]:   12: <unknown>
Sep 22 17:04:11 bobcat systemd[1]: aziot-identityd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 22 17:04:11 bobcat systemd[1]: aziot-identityd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.```
````

Comment: Could you please confirm if you are able to delete the certificate and reset the device?

Comment: Have you reviewed the following article that explains [How to roll device certificates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/core/how-to-connect-devices-x509?pivots=programming-language-csharp)